# WPF datagrid issue

Tags: c#, datagrid

Is it possible to set one or multiple rows' background color?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AlternatingRowBackground` property to do every other row.  Do you need to do specific rows?  Like only rows 1, 5, and 9?  Or different background color depending on data?

**EDITED:** edited per comment..

Doing it data based can be done like this...

```
<DataGrid 
    AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Height="200" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="156,58,0,0" 
    Name="dataGrid1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="200" LoadingRow="dataGrid1_LoadingRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    list.Add("test1");
    list.Add("test2");
    list.Add("test3");
    list.Add("test4");
    list.Add("test5");

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
}

private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Item.ToString().Contains("test"))
    {
        e.Row.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, different background color depending on data, is it possible? how to do that?

Comment: In my case, there are several columns, so should i use: e.Row.Item.ToString().Contains=="xxxx" ? but it doesnt work..

Comment: `Contains` is a method.  so your code would be... `if (e.Row.Item.ToString().Contains("xxx")) ....